# Frozen meat in freezers on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, food, muktzeh

Assuming frozen meat is muktzah on Shabbos, let's say that frozen meat fell out of the freezer and if it's not put back on Shabbos it will spoil, causing monetary loss.
Or, let's talk about a case where one has ice cream or any other food like frozen Challah that is needed for a Shabbos meal in back of the freezer, and in order to get it some frozen meat has to be moved.

What can be done in either of the above cases?

Comment: See also http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/5824

Answer (score 6):

Raw fowl is not *muktza* according to *Shulchan Aruch* (308:31-32, *Mishna B'rura* :125), as some eat it. Although we do not rely on this for four-legged-animal meat (*Mishna B'rura* :125, quoting the *Magen Avraham*), we do in a situation of *d'chak* (*Mishna B'rura* :125). Now, *Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* (11 footnote 20) quotes R' S.Z. Auerbach as saying that since nowadays no one eats raw meat, we cannot rely this. (Does he mean for land-animal meat only? Or even for fowl? I don't know.) Do "we" hold of R' Auerbach? (It seems telling that *SSK* does not seem to use his ruling in the main text: only in a footnote.) As always [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR). (The above synopses are my own; don't rely on them!)

Comment: And people eat raw meat in fact the Pay an awful lot for it.
Beef Tartar
http://www.epicurious.com/tools/fooddictionary/entry?id=1317

Comment: I was told that even a gangster(lake that son-of-Drusai) wouldn't eat it! ;-)

Comment: most of the kulos are indeed in the footnotes, in the Hebrew text, of Shmiras Shabbos Kehilchasah.

Comment: @joshwaxman Yes, but in this case he seems to be bringing a Ḥumrah in the footnote. What does it all mean???

Comment: I've changed the question slightly to remove request for p'sak, along with some odd capital letters. I also made more explicit something that I think was there from the start -- the assumption that frozen meat is muktzah. Your answer does not address that, though.

Comment: @Shokhet, when I read the question I assumed it was about raw frozen meat, not cooked frozen meat. Rereading it now, I see that I may have been mistaken.

Comment: @msh210 Are you referring to the old question, or to the edited question?

Comment: @Shokhet, both. Either.

Comment: @msh210 Okay. Hopefully the fact that this question got bumped by a recent edit will bring it some new attention.